# CreateMultipartUploadCommand response does not include ETag and CompleteMultipartUploadCommand fail in aws-sdk v3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

CreateMultipartUploadCommand response does not include ETag and CompleteMultipartUploadCommand fail

#### create

```
 const s3Client = new S3Client({ region, credentials  });
  const input: CreateMultipartUploadCommandInput = {
    Bucket: s3BucketName,
    Key: filePath,
  };
    const multipartUploadResponse = await s3Client.send(new CreateMultipartUploadCommand(input));
    const uploadId = multipartUploadResponse.UploadId;
```

create success and got uploadId

#### upload

```
    const uploadParams: UploadPartCommandInput = {
        Body: fileObject.slice(start, end + 1),
        Bucket: s3BucketName,
        Key: filePath,
        UploadId: uploadId,
        PartNumber: i,
      };
      const result = await s3Client.send(new UploadPartCommand(uploadParams));
      uploaded.push({PartNumber: i+1, ETag: result.ETag }) // this result does not include ETag so it is undefined
```

Although http response of this command include **ETag** in *http header*,
the result of `s3Client.send(new UploadPartCommand(uploadParams)` does not include **ETag**

#### complete

```
      const completeParams: CompleteMultipartUploadCommandInput = {
        Bucket: AwsConfigS3.s3BucketName,
        Key: filePath,
        UploadId: uploadId,
        MultipartUpload: {
          Parts: uploaded,
        },
      };
      const response = await s3Client.send(new CompleteMultipartUploadCommand(completeParams));
```

this command throw error with **The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema**